# Terminated due to timeout error

Tags: java, optimization

My function find consecutive sums fails a test case due to a timeout. Can anyone look at this and maybe help with optimization?

```
   static int consecutive(long num) {
            return  consecutiveHelper(num);
    }

public static int consecutiveHelper(long num){
    int factorNumber = 1;
    int count = 0;
     while(factorNumber <= num){
            if(num % factorNumber == 0 && (factorNumber%2 != 0)){
          count++;
            }
            factorNumber ++;
        }

    return count-1;

}
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once.